# HLS stream skipping some frames before #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, http-live-streaming

I am playing an HLS stream using Android VideoView in 4.0.3 OS.

The stream is played but I observe certain frames are getting skipped off just before the discontinuity tag .The segment that comes just before the #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag is getting skipped by certain frames towards the end. I have tried playing the stream using Mediaplayer too and the result is the same.

Has any of you come across a similar issue? If yes please suggest a solution!

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution ?